# Building object names from variables?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

Sorry for this Newbie question, but it would help me a lot and I can't find a solution:

I want to use a string which I get from a database as object name like this:

NSString *objectName = **string from Database**

[self.**objectName**.titlelabel ....

In this case it would be setting a font for a button label.

How can this be achieved in Objective-C? The answers I found with NSMutableDictionary didn't help me.

Comment: What was wrong with a dictionary?  `self.objectDict[objectName].titlelabel`

Answer (score -1):

`NSString *objectName` doesn't have a `titleLabel` `property`, however you could set the `titleLabel` of another `UIButton` as the string in `objectName`